# API to Twitter Analytics

Tags: api, csv, twitter, analytics

I am currently exporting CSV files from Twitter Analytics for Impressions, Engagement and Cost purposes for a dashboarding and analysis tool.

Does Twitter have an API for that? Do they provide it for high paying clients only? I was told that some companies are able to download the insights automatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They currently don't offer a public API for that (frustrating), but I wrote a Python script that logs in and downloads the CSV programmatically: https://github.com/ashleycoxley/twitter-analytics-export

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I rewrite it in PHP? I will give it a try.

Comment: Seems like Twitter is blocking the script now. Currently returns a 403 error.

Comment: That's true. Should I remove this answer?

Comment: @ashleycoxley Is twitter still blocking the script? If so,  after how many runs?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party. There is a hackish python package that does the work.

```
$ pip install twitter-analytics
```

More here: https://github.com/philippe2803/twitter-analytics-wrapper
Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't offer a public API for that, but there are paid services that have free trials if this isn't a regular task. Crowdbabble creates data visualizations using the Twitter API and can export to CSV, PDF, or PNG (or scheduled reports that go to your email automatically). They download the insights via the API.